# Как изменить цвет во всех классах которые указаны в JCheckBox

Tags: java

Как изменить цвет GUI во всех классах с помощью одного класса и JCheckBox'a когда нажимаешь на него меняется цвет к примеру на красный когда снимаешь галочку цвет ставится на по умолчанию как это сделать?

Comment: про какой цвет идет речь?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Что то типа CodeClass.this.setBackground - MainGui.this.setBackground и все это надо как то сделать с-помощью одного класса в котором есть JCheckBox

Answer (score 0):

Во всех классах с помощью одного класса? Что? Вы это имеете в виду?

```
JCheckBox jCheckBox = new JCheckBox();
jCheckBox.addActionListener(e -> {
    if(jCheckBox.isSelected()) jCheckBox.setBackground(Color.RED);
    else jCheckBox.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
});
```

Создайте собственный класс `MyJCheckBox`, и в его конструкторе пропишите добавление слушателя:

```
class MyJCheckBox extends JCheckBox {
    public MyJCheckBox() {
        addActionListener(e -> {
            if(isSelected()) setBackground(Color.RED);
            else setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Что то типа CodeClass.this.setBackground MainGui.this.setBackground и все это надо как то сделать с помощью одного класса в котором есть JCheckBox

Comment: Я уже такое пробовал не помогло меняет цвет только в одном классе мне надо во всех у меня классы разделены Есть Main.class есть Code.class ну и т.д и в них в основном используется JPanel есть отдельное меню с JCheckBox'om когда нажимаешь на него должен меняться цвет во всех классах я так и не нашел ответа на свой вопрос с этим перепробовал разные схемы добавления кратко перебрал весь интернет

Comment: Что значит менялось во всех классах? Класс - это не объект, не приложение. Вы хотите запустить одно приложение, запустить второе, а потом в одном приложении нажать на кнопку, и чтобы у вас во всех запущенных приложениях сменился цвет?

Comment: Нет на данный момент я использую CodeClass.this.setBackground для других классов это не работает то есть пишет ошибку то что не может работать с другими классами - может работать только в классе в котором это было написано

Comment: Что такое CodeClass?

Comment: Это класс в котором находятся все элементы GUI когда пытаюсь использовать this для другого класса выводит вот это No enclosing instance of the type CodeClass is accessible in scope